# Autogenerated PHP page after somsone fills in a form

Tags: php, html, mysql, auto-generate

how to make a autogenerated page in this style  after someone fills in registration-form:

```
            <div class="data">
                <h1>Name of the User</h1>
                <h3>Age of the user</h3>
                <h4><a href="http://letstalk.nl.ae">www.letstalk.nl.ae</a></h4>
                <div class="sep"></div>
                <ul class="numbers clearfix">
                    <li>Reputatie<strong>0</strong></li>
                    <li>Badges<strong>0</strong></li>
                    <li class="nobrdr">Checkins<strong>0</strong></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>`
```

At the moment i am using HTML, PHP, MySQL.

Comment: do you mean replacing `<h1>Name of the User</h1>` with `<h1>HTMLboy001</h1>` and so on? You can do that with javascript (yeah, with PHP too). What do you prefer?

Comment: When I read autogenerated, I think of something like `fopen()`. Just write a file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing the registration page values to Database, you can fetch from table and show. Otherwise you are directly posting values to the page means, you can do it like this,

```
<div class="data">
                <h1>Name of the User : <?php echo $_POST['name']; ?></h1>
                <h3>Age of the user : <?php echo $_POST['age']; ?></h3>
                <h4><a href="http://letstalk.nl.ae">www.letstalk.nl.ae</a></h4>
                <div class="sep"></div>
                <ul class="numbers clearfix">
                    <li>Reputatie<strong>0</strong></li>
                    <li>Badges<strong>0</strong></li>
                    <li class="nobrdr">Checkins<strong>0</strong></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Replace `<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>`, `<?php echo $_POST['age']; ?>` with your DB values in the first case i mentioned above

Comment: Thank you! i am going to try this.